# How to use FREAK as part of BOW

Tags: opencv, freak

I've some code running that performs object categorization using the *BOW-frame* provided by **OpenCV**.

And as long as I use *SIFT* or *SURF* as DescriptorExtractor everything is fine.

Now I want to use FREAK as DescriptorExtractor. As my first step I collect all descriptors of all images. When I use FREAK I  must add a conversation 
`descriptor.convertTo(descriptor, CV_32F);`, or the cluster method throws an exception. So far so good.

Then as I try to generate my labeled responses for each image using  `bowide_->compute(image, keypoints, result);`

I get an exception OpenCV `Error: Assertion failed (queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescCollection[0].type()) in knnMatchImpl, file /home/kastor/Development/opencv-2.4.7/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp, line 351
queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescCollection[0].type().`

The next step would be to train the SVM.
As I said the whole thing works for SIFT and SURF. Any ideas if it is possible 
to use FREAK in the same manner or if I need to do some more conversion ?

I tried different matchers, but no success.

Thanks in advance